# Collapsing a dataframe to identify all variations across columns

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
x <- structure(list(X1 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), X2 = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "STREET_NAME", "NA", "NA"), X3 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "STREET_TYPE_CODE", "NA"), X4 = c("NA", "LOCALITY_NAME", 
"NA", "STREET_NAME", "NA", "NA"), X5 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "STREET_NAME", 
"NA", "STATE")), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Ideally I want to collapse the dataframe and remove "NA" values.

If the entire column contain's "NA"'s, I want to classify the column as "UNKNOWN".

I then want to use a function similar to `expand.grid` to create a dataframe of all variations across each row when not "NA", so in the above example it would return (something like)...

```
     Var1        Var2             Var3          Var4        Var5
1 UNKNOWN STREET_NAME STREET_TYPE_CODE LOCALITY_NAME STREET_NAME
2 UNKNOWN STREET_NAME STREET_TYPE_CODE   STREET_NAME STREET_NAME
3 UNKNOWN STREET_NAME STREET_TYPE_CODE LOCALITY_NAME       STATE
4 UNKNOWN STREET_NAME STREET_TYPE_CODE   STREET_NAME       STATE
```

I am iterating through thousands of data.frames similar to x above, however, all have different dimensions.

I could easily enough do this through a for loop, however, want to be as concise and fast as possible.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop over the columns, get the `unique` elements that are not a missing value (`x != "NA"` - In the OP's dataset, the missing values were quoted which is incorrect way of handling missing values.  It should be unquoted i.e. `NA` and then we can use `is.na` or `complete.cases` etc.), and do the `expand.grid`

```
res <- expand.grid(lapply(x, function(x) {
         x1 <- unique(x[x!= "NA"])
       if(length(x1)==0) "UNKNOWN" else x1}))
names(res) <- paste0("Var", seq_along(res))
res
#    Var1        Var2             Var3          Var4        Var5
#1 UNKNOWN STREET_NAME STREET_TYPE_CODE LOCALITY_NAME STREET_NAME
#2 UNKNOWN STREET_NAME STREET_TYPE_CODE   STREET_NAME STREET_NAME
#3 UNKNOWN STREET_NAME STREET_TYPE_CODE LOCALITY_NAME       STATE
#4 UNKNOWN STREET_NAME STREET_TYPE_CODE   STREET_NAME       STATE
```

---

Or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
    summarise_all(funs(list(unique(.[.!= "NA"])))) %>% 
    map(~ if(lengths(.x)==0) "UNKNOWN" else unlist(.x))  %>%
    expand.grid %>%
    rename_all(~ paste0("Var", 1:5))
```